# Web FTP Portal Logins

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I have a web ftp portal that was created a few years ago by a developer that is no longer around.  The code for the website is written in Node.js.  Inside of app.js is the following code:

```
    var validUsers = [{
    name:'x',
    user:'907c78ef73998eafc2680e5fdd4798a8eef0881a',
    pass:'95489cf3039eb2f5938e3daa954d04276bbf90e7',
    dir:''
},{
    name:'y',
    user:'b26e5ebda152e81099ec78be2f9c191ee25e1cd6',
    pass:'e3725873ae302e3f12eb97b02feb7457de9706c2',
    dir:'y'
},{
    name:'y2',
    user:'3182b54d9f4d08641b5a9a0fb33f74df5d76b222',
    pass:'916b2e1941c9e23610f8bd3462cdb19f55b5c631',
    dir:'y2'
},{
    name:'y3',
    user:'38aa53de31c04bcfae9163cc23b7963ed9cf90f7',
    pass:'7a98cf84c2c61a30f6c4e3984c0cad2eb29f5d6f',
    dir:'y3'
},{
    name:'y4',
    user:'51e822c50cc62cdbdb850a439ea75b6d45ac487b',
    pass:'da6a77293ddcdc7047dd461a94c88c8377753265',
    dir:'y4'
},{
    name:'y5',
    user:'14ad0aca26e00f615990946181ee3405c6ede0f1',
    pass:'4eb4e0e1ea0f04422b5bc6031ee37c8dc971236d',
    dir:'y5'
},{
    name:'y6',
    user:'4ec9bdb28c5da0f9813e9eed55a0f1dc6217a305',
    pass:'e72bd0bbd37423bb0c9b9edfb9ce94446161c511',
    dir:'y6'
},{
    name:'y7',
    user:'f4603bd4ae9e4aa2a11d903d0b178b37a57b1bac',
    pass:'8a6a67f235738c4b2e4f88d4608bdcf0bbc49f51',
    dir:'y7'
},{
    name:'Guest',
    user:'35675e68f4b5af7b995d9205ad0fc43842f16450',
    pass:'370bb444ef91a3999b1c36af97e166f18848e7b7',
    dir:'Guest'
},{
    name:'y8',
    user:'d8f51fbf5e13e9f2637a8d5c4bd1ab251bd61c30',
    pass:'1a047e6dd554ffdd67524916820a8fa23acd2c6e',
    dir:'y8'
}];
```

The x and y1-8 are substitutions for the actual client names and corresponding directories.  Example being the 'Guest' name and directory.  My question is, the user and pass are hash values from crypto.  Yet they result in specific usernames and passwords.  If I wanted to reset a username or password, or add another.  How would I figure out the corresponding hash value to add to the code based on the username/password strings I want to add.

Any input would be very helpful.

EDIT:

The rest of the FTP code:

```
    app.get('/ftp/', function(req, res){
var pageName = 'File Transfer Portal';
var rNav = '',
    sNav = '',
    cNav = '',
    imNav = '',
    title = 'companyNameOmitted: '+pageName,
    bodyClass = 'top ftp',
    keywords = 'keywordsOmitted',
    description = 'descriptionOmiited',
    url = '/ftp/';

res.render('ftp', { 
    title: title, 
    bodyClass: bodyClass,
    keywords: keywords, 
    description: description,
    url: siteRoot+url,
    pageEmail: 'mailto:?subject='+escape(title)+'&body='+escape(description)+'%0A'+siteRoot+url,
    eUrl:escape(siteRoot+url),
    eTitle:escape(title),
    eDescription:escape(description),
    rNav:rNav,
    sNav:sNav,
    cNav:cNav,
    imNav:imNav});
//console.log(uniqId()+':'+pageName);
});

    app.post('/ftp/upload', function(req, res){
//console.log(req.files);
var SID = req.cookies.SID;
var sessionUser = (users[SID]) ? users[SID] : false;
if (!!sessionUser){
    _.each(req.files,function (file) {
        console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | Recieved '+file.name+' ('+file.size+' bytes) from '+sessionUser.name);

        var newPath = __dirname + '/complete/'+_.where(validUsers,{user:sessionUser.user})[0].dir+'/'+file.name;
        fs.rename(file.path,newPath,function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
                res.redirect('back');
                if (sessionUser.name != 'adminOmitted') {
                    var htmlString = '<b>'+sessionUser.name+'</b> has uploaded a file <b>'+file.name+'</b>.<br /><br />View it on the <a href="https://url/ftp/">File Transfer Portal</a>.';

                    var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
                        host: "hostname.com", // hostname
                        secureConnection: true, // use SSL
                        port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
                        auth: {
                            user: "user@host.com",
                            pass: "pass"
                        }
                    });

                    transport.sendMail({
                        sender:'sender@host.com',
                        to:'receiver@host.com',
                        subject:'File Upload: '+sessionUser.name+' uploaded '+file.name,
                        html: htmlString
                    },function(err) {
                        if (err) console.log(err);
                        else console.log('Notification Sent: S&A File Upload: '+sessionUser.name+' uploaded '+file.name);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

And the login code...

```
    app.get('/ftp/d/:hash/:filename', function(req, res){
var SID = req.cookies.SID;
var ip = req.ip;
//console.log(ip);
var sessionUser = (users[SID]) ? ((users[SID].md5==req.params.hash)&&(users[SID].ip==ip)) ? users[SID] : false : false;
if (sessionUser) {
    var realpath = __dirname +'/complete/'+_.where(validUsers,{user:sessionUser.user})[0].dir+'/'+req.params.filename.replace('>','/');
    console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | Sending '+realpath.substr(realpath.indexOf('complete')+9)+' to '+sessionUser.name);
    res.download(realpath,realpath.substr(realpath.lastIndexOf('/')+1),function(err){
        if (err) {
            res.redirect(302,'/ftp/');
            throw (err);
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | Download request failed authorization for '+req.params.filename);
    console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | Hash: '+req.params.hash);
    console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | SID: '+req.cookies.SID);
    res.redirect(302,'/ftp/');
}
});

sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var SID = socket.handshake.SID;
        if (!users[SID]) register(SID,socket.handshake.address.address);

//console.log(users);
socket.on('login',function(data) {
    var thisUser = _.where(validUsers,{user:data.u,pass:data.p})[0];

    if (_.isEmpty(thisUser)) {
        if (!!users[SID].ip) {
            console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | '+users[SID].ip+' has failed logging in.');
            console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | '+'U:'+data.u);
            console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | '+'P:'+data.p);
        }
        socket.emit('login',{complete:false,name:false});
    } else {
        console.log(new Date(curTime()).toGMTString()+' | '+thisUser.name+' has logged in.');
        users[SID].name = thisUser.name;
        users[SID].user = thisUser.user;
        socket.emit('login',{complete:true,name:thisUser.name});
    }
});
```

And the disconnect function, the only code between the login and the disconnect functions are a move file and a delete file function which I doubt are of any use.

```
    //console.log(users);
socket.on('disconnect',function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!!users[SID]) {
            if (curTime()-users[SID].lastTap>30000)
                unregister(SID);
            else console.log('Not removing; connection still active. ('+users[SID].name+')');
        } else (unregister(SID));
    },30000);
});
});
```

and finally, the crypto functions:

```
    function getMD5(string) {
return crypto.
    createHash('md5').
    update(string).
    digest("hex");
}

function getSHA1(string) {
        return crypto.
        createHash('sha1').
        update(string).
        digest("hex");
}
```

I know the formatting isn't perfect, I've tried to keep it as neat as possible, I think that's all of the relevant functions.  I doubt the .jade file for the FTP Portal would be of any use.

Comment: figure out where in the code the entered user/passes get converted back to those values so the logins can be verified. that'll tell you exactly what's necessary for you to generate your own. Since you've provided no actual node, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Added more code, if any functions are missing or anything let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The usernames and passwords have been put through an asymmetric encryption (ie MD5). This was likely done to protect the user's personal information if the server is hacked.

You're still missing the part of the code that handles the authentication and sets the session cookie.

If you can find the code that handles the auth and you know the username beforehand you could re-hash it to cross-reference the username to the entries list.

Otherwise, your only option is to crack the usernames/passwords which can be difficult/impossible depending on their complexity.

Good luck...